# Create new function instead of overriding paintComponent

Tags: java, user-interface, overriding

```
class MultiplicationTablePanel extends JPanel {
     @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        g.drawString("Multiplication Table", 0, 0);
```

If I want to draw something on Panel, I need to override paintComponent function. If I want to create a new function instead of override, such as 
     "protected void testPaintComponent(Graphics g)"

It doesn't work, the panel show nothing. What is the reason behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Swing will call `paintComponent` when the component should be drawn. If you invent a new method Swing won't know about it and it won't be called.

If you want to name your method

```
protected void testPaintComponent(Graphics g) { ... }
```

you have to make sure `paintComponent` delegates to this method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    testPaintComponent(g);
}
```